# Foursquare API twitter checkin count

Tags: foursquare

My application is authenticating the user and I am able to access user Checkin details but I need details with respect to checkin shared on twitter or facebook.

Is it possible to get those details from Foursquare API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foursquare API does not include information about whether or not a specific check-in was shared to Twitter/Facebook.

For a list of check-in information returned by the API, see the documented response object: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/checkin

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am able to fetch total check-ins details but want to find specifically Twitter or Facebook share check-ins.

Any idea about it.

Comment: The only facebook/twitter sharing information exposed via the API is via the merchant platform, tied to a single venue. There is no way to get share information from a user level without using the Twitter/Facebook APIs